# How do I use MATLAB's substruct function to create a struct representing a reference that uses "end"?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to use the [`substruct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/substruct.html) function to create a structure for use in `subsref`. The purpose is to index a string using `subsref` instead of the usual `( )` notation because I'm subscripting the output of a function. This is a *simple* example of what I'm trying to do (in my actual code, this is used within a `cellfun`, so the strings can be of different lengths and the replacement isn't always in the same place):

```
data = 'quick brown fox';
data2 = strrep(data, 'brown', 'green');
data2(7:end)
```

Heres where I tried to define this subscripting with `substruct`:

```
data = 'quick brown fox';
S = substruct('()', {[7:end]});
subsref(strrep(data, 'brown', 'green'), S)
```

but this just gives me an error:

```
Error using substruct (line 30)
SUBSTRUCT takes at least two arguments.

Error in myfile (line 3)
S = substruct('()', {(7:end)});
```

I've been over and over the documentation for both `substruct` and `subsref`, and no where do they mention `end`. How do I do this?

Comment: What about just changing `end` into `numel(data)`?

Comment: Marcin is right, numel(data) fixes it.  Turns out, `end` can only be used to index an actual array, not create a struct array (i.e., S) to be used in a subsref.

Comment: `numel(data)` is incorrect since it calculates the length of `data` BEFORE `strrep`. If the length changes, it will error.

There is no way to my knowledge to do that with `subsref`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to my knowledge to do that with `subsref` which assumes you know exactly which `subs` you will need.

Use `@function_handle` to dynamically determine the `end`:

```
f = @(x) x(7:end);
f(strrep(data, 'brown', ''))
ans =
  fox
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. In my original example, I wasn't *removing* the word 'brown', so the answer should be 'green fox', but you're right in that it doesnt look like `subsref` will handle this.