# Create indexing array with 'end' before vector exists

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, matrix-indexing

I was just wondering if there is a way to index using `end` before knowing a vector's size? It should work for arrays with different sizes. Like this:

```
subvector = (2:end) % illegal use of end

A=[1 2 3];
B=[4 5 6 7];

A(subvector) % should be 2 3
B(subvector) % should be 5 6 7
```

Comment: I'm thinking the way you are trying to go about it would all result in illegal use of end. Maybe try making a string and see if you can convert the string to an index? Try [str2func](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html)

Comment: [eval](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) may work better for what you want.

Comment: @medicine_man Safely assume that `eval` never works *better*

Comment: @medicine_man read [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32467170/5211833) and references contained therein to blogs by MathWorks employees amongst others as to why using `eval` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: [The highest voted question in the MATLAB tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627107/5211833) might be relevant here. Not a dupe, but closely related nonetheless.

Comment: Another closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508157/how-do-i-use-matlabs-substruct-function-to-create-a-struct-representing-a-refer

Comment: Haven't used eval much, but never any security problems or run time issues.

Comment: @medicine_man These articles might be of interest: [docs: "Alternatives to the eval function"](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html), [MathWorks blog: "Evading eval"](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/), SO questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46179940/3978545, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46213509/3978545

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up an anonymous function to act in a similar way

```
f_end = @(v) v(2:end);

A = [1 2 3];
B = [4 5 6 7];

f_end( A ); % = [2 3];
f_end( B ); % = [5 6 7];
```

I think this is the only way you could do it, since you can't set up an indexing array without knowing the `end` index.

Answer (score 1):

Without indexing or usage of `end`, one can remove the first element:

```
f_end = A;
f_end[1] = [];
```

As a function:

```
function x = f_end(y, n)
    x = y;
    x[1:n]=[]; % deletes the first n elements
```

Comment: I guess this involves an intermediate step, say if I wanted to use the indexed array but preserve the whole array, I'd have to create a copy and remove the initial elements?

Comment: @Wolfie yes, removing elements changes the shape of an array. This is indeed a drawback of the method.